# Rcpp loop update variable inside

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, armadillo

I am a new user of Rcpp and I am writing an package. 
I have defined two functions in one script and try to call one from another in the loop.

One of my function defined as below:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double timesTwo(colvec x, NumericVector group, double k,
                NumericVector unique_group)

{
  vec beta(x.begin(),x.size(),false);
  vec Group(group.begin(),group.size(),false);
  vec unigroup(unique_group.begin(),unique_group.size(),false);
  beta = pow(beta,k);
  int g = unigroup.size();
  int j = 0;
  uvec st ;
  double  b=0;
  for(j = 0; j < g; j++)
  {
    st = find(Group == unigroup[j]);
    b  = b + abs(pow(sum(beta.elem(st)),1/k));
  }
  double s = b;
  return s;
}
```

And the loop I use to to call this function is like below:

```
 XtXi_beta_plus.col(i)  =  X_MAT * BETA_NEW.col(2*i); 
 XtXi_beta_minus.col(i) = X_MAT * BETA_NEW.col(2*i+1);  
 loss_new_1.col(i) = (Y - ited / (ited + exp( -XtXi_beta_plus.col(i))));
 loss_new_2.col(i) = (Y - ited / (ited + exp( -XtXi_beta_minus.col(i))));
 new_loss(2*i)    = accu(loss_new_1.col(i) % loss_new_1.col(i));
 new_loss(2*i+1)  = accu(loss_new_2.col(i) % loss_new_2.col(i));
 z = BETA_NEW.col(2*i);
 w = BETA_NEW.col(2*i+1);

 // when 88 line was change to BETA_NEW.col(2*i) there is an error
 // if you keep use Z, there is no update
 // best! 

 pen_new_positive(i) =  as<double>(timesTwo(z,group,k,unique_group));
```

My question is just like the comment I said in the loop, since I want to update that `pen_new_postive(i)` based on the `BETA_NEW.col(2*i)` However when I directly put `BETA_NEW.COL(2*i)` inside the `timesTwo` function, no matter how I change input 
type of function (`colvec` or `mat` or whatever) there is error like below:

```
  cannot convert "const::arma::subview_col<double> to "SEXP" in 
  initialization"
```

However when I directly use `z` in the `timesTwo` function, there is no update for my `z` in the loop.

Anyone could give me a hint about how to deal with this?

The full version of my code in second block as below:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <math.h>
//#include <omp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;



  //// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]
  // [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
  // [[Rcpp::export]]
    List minghan21041(NumericMatrix beta_new, NumericVector diff_loss, 
                  NumericVector beta, double step_size, NumericVector y, 
             double k,
                  NumericVector group,
                  NumericVector unique_group,
                  NumericMatrix X) {






   int n = X.nrow(),  p=X.ncol() , n1=beta_new.nrow(), p1=beta_new.ncol();
   mat X_MAT(X.begin(),n,p,false),  BETA_NEW(beta_new.begin(),n1,p1,false);
   vec BETA(beta.begin(),beta.size(),false);
   vec Y(y.begin(),y.size(),false), 
   Diff_Loss(diff_loss.begin(),diff_loss.size(),false), iter(p,fill::zeros);  
   mat XtXi_beta_plus(n,p,fill::zeros);
   mat XtXi_beta_minus(n,p,fill::zeros);
   vec ited(n,fill::ones);       
   mat loss_new_1(n,p, fill::zeros),loss_new_2(n,p, fill::zeros);
   colvec loss_new_3(n,fill::zeros);
   vec new_loss(p1,fill::zeros);
   uword index;
   vec beta_final(p,fill::zeros);


   vec pen_new_positive(p,fill::zeros);
   vec pen_new_negative(p,fill::zeros);

   double pen_old = 0;  
   Function timesTwo( "timesTwo" ); 
   double cs=0;

   //Col dc(BETA.begin(),p,1);
   //pen_old = as<double>(timesTwo(dc,group,k,unique_group));

   vec z(p,fill::zeros);  
   vec w(p,fill::zeros);  
   int i = 0; 
   vec XtXi_beta_old = X_MAT*BETA;
   loss_new_3= (Y - ited / (ited + exp(-XtXi_beta_old)));
   double loss_old_one = accu(loss_new_3%loss_new_3);

 //#pragma omp parallel private(i) num_threads(4)
 //{
 //#pragma omp for ordered schedule(static,1)  
 for(i= 0; i<p; i++){

 //#pragma omp ordered
 //{

    iter(i) = step_size;
    BETA_NEW.col(2*i)   = BETA + iter;
    BETA_NEW.col(2*i+1) = BETA - iter;

    XtXi_beta_plus.col(i)  =  X_MAT * BETA_NEW.col(2*i); 
    XtXi_beta_minus.col(i) = X_MAT * BETA_NEW.col(2*i+1);  
    loss_new_1.col(i) = (Y - ited / (ited + exp( -XtXi_beta_plus.col(i))));
    loss_new_2.col(i) = (Y - ited / (ited + exp( -XtXi_beta_minus.col(i))));
    new_loss(2*i)    = accu(loss_new_1.col(i) % loss_new_1.col(i));
    new_loss(2*i+1)  = accu(loss_new_2.col(i) % loss_new_2.col(i));
    z = BETA_NEW.col(2*i);
    w = BETA_NEW.col(2*i+1);

    // when 88 line was change to BETA_NEW.col(2*i) there is an error
    // if you keep use Z, there is no update, you can source this file and I 
    //believe there is no other error 
    // best! 

    pen_new_positive(i) =  as<double>(timesTwo(BETA_NEW.col(2*i),group,k,unique_group));

     cs = pen_new_positive(i);
     //Rcout << "cs" << cs << std::endl;
     Rcout << "cs" <<  z << std::endl;
     //pen_new_negative =  as< std::vector<double> >(time(w,group,k,unique_group));  
     Diff_Loss(2*i)   = new_loss(2*i)   - loss_old_one + cs;
     Diff_Loss(2*i+1) = new_loss(2*i+1) - loss_old_one + cs;
     iter(i) = 0;
    }

    //}
   //}




       index = Diff_Loss.index_min();
       beta_final = BETA_NEW.col(index);
      return List::create( _["index"]    = wrap(index),
                 _["Diff_Loss"]= wrap(Diff_Loss[index]),
                 _["ste"]      =wrap(Diff_Loss),
                 _["beta_new"] = wrap(beta_final),
                 _["New_LOSS"]= wrap(new_loss[index]),
                 _["t"] = wrap(pen_new_positive)); 
       }
```

Comment: Please post _all_ of the affected code. Not just a snippet.

Comment: Hi coatless, I have update the all of affected as you required. I wonder if you could help me out from this. Thx a lot @coatless

Comment: Please clean up your posted code snippet. Make sure it is using the correct function that you are highlighting.

Comment: I think I am using the correct function that I am highlighting which is timesTwo As I defined in the first chunk of the code. I believe the first input of my function can be vec or Colvec. @coatless